# Append before closing body tag in python

Tags: python, template-engine

ok guys so I have a template.html file like so:

```
<h1>Hello wolrd</h1>
<div>This is me</div>
```

And I want to append that to my index file before the closing body tag. Just like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/template.html">
<h1>Hello wolrd</h1>
<div>This is me</div> 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've so far gotten to read the file and append to the end of it but I have yet to add the script tags to the file that I am reading and append to the correct spot of my file. This is what I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

to_readfile=open('index.html', "r")
try:
  reading_file=to_readfile.read()

  writefile=open('index2.html','a')
  try:
    writefile.write("\n")
    writefile.write(reading_file)
  finally:
    writefile.close()

finally:
  to_readfile.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There a reason why you can't use jinja?

Comment: Yes basically I want to transition from an angularJS application built with Yeoman.io to an application that runs serverles. So that if I zip  the application and some one opens the index.html file the app still runs. This can be achieved by not ajaxing in the templates but rather inserting them directly into the index file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to add a placeholder in the layout template and then when processing the layout search for the placeholder and replace it with the contents of the other template.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/template.html">
{{content}}
</script>

</body>
</html>

...
..
.
layout = open('layout.html', "r")
layout_contents = layout.read()

partial=open('partial_file.html','r')
result = layout_contents.replace("{{content}}", partial)

writefile = open("file_to_write.html", "w")
writefile.write("\n")
writefile.write(result)
.
..
....
```

You can also work on a much more extensive solution such as the ones used by jinja http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance.

Comment: If instead of putting the placeholder I would use the "</body>" tag as a place holder and then replace with my partial+"</body>" would that work to?